# Loop is not running for mentioned time

Tags: c, loops

In the first 'for' loop, no matter how big i am giving the value of n, it is running for exactly one time. Why?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, a[6], i, j, n1, n2;
    float area=0.00, ma=0, mia=0;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<=6; j++)
            scanf("%d", &a[j]);

        area = (a[1]*(a[4]-a[6])+a[3]*(a[6]-a[2])+a[5]*(a[2]-a[4]))/2;

        if(area<0)
            area = -area;

        if(i == 0)
            mia = area;

        if(area >= ma)
        {
            ma = area;
            n1 = i;
        }

        if(area <= mia)
        {
            mia = area;
            n2 = i;
        }

    }
    printf("\n%d %d", n1, n2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *What* is exactly running one time? The printf statement? The loop? Since the printf statement is outside the loop, it should only run once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overrunning `a` here:

```
for(j=1;j<=6;j++)
  scanf("%d",&a[j]);
```

(the last time through the loop, you're writing to `a[6]`, when only `a[0]` through `a[5]` exist)

Remember that in C, arrays are indexed starting with `0`, not `1`.

There's a good chance that last assignment is overwriting `i`, depending one where your variables live in memory.  The next time through the loop, `i` is equal to whatever you last input, plus `1`.

Alternatively, `n` may be overwritten. All sorts of things may be happening. Either adjust your indices, or (as a quick test) change the declaration to:

```
int n,a[7],i,j,n1,n2;
```

and see if things behave better.

Comment: Thanks! Now i am getting correct ans.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `printf` in the first `for` loop, you will know it runs `n+1` times, not just once. I just run your code on my local machine with `n=3`.